# Python-Flask, Server generated from swagger file produces 'do some magic!' for all get methods

Tags: python, flask, swagger-codegen

I have generated Python Flask-Server API from swagger editor:
https://editor.swagger.io/

When I run the server locally, I noticed that all my get methods produce the same output:
'do some magic!'

I have replaced that phrase in all my controllers methods, and restarted the server. But it still generates that stupid output instead of the expected ones. Where does it come from?
[image]

Here is the way to reproduce the problem:

1. go to https://editor.swagger.io/ and create simple interface with one method
2. generate server code python-flask
3. open it in IDE (I am using VS Code on Windows), go to controllers, update return of you methos, and run  ./swagger_server/**main**.py
4. when the server is ready to respond, call that method (http://localhost:8080/yourmethod) and you will notice that it always returns 'do some magic!' regardless of what your controller contains

```
def module_health_check():  # noqa: E501
    return 'do another magic!'
```

But if you build Docker and run it as a container, it will call your controller properly as expected. I think something wrong with my dev environment settings in Windows Visual Studio Code, which generates stub result in run time (without docker)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have updated my question with steps to reproduce the problem

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think I have found a solution shortly described here
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/tutorial-flask
It seems like my VS Code IDE behaves differently:

- when you run _ _ *main* _ _.py (or app.py - default for Flask) directly, it generates that stupid message for ALL methods
- and it works correctly, when you run it as described in that doco: python -m swagger_server